# How to make this div section with text, button, and textbox responsive in all screen size smoothly?

Tags: html, css

I have my code for @media but it doesn't align well. I hope you can help me align the contents from 320px to 767 for mobile. and 768px to 800px for tablet. Is my html code right? I cant align the contents smoothly :(

html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid header-subscribe-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <p>
                                <span class="header-p-latestmenus font-Awesome white">Get our latest games in your inbox.</span>
                                <span class="header-p-subscribe font-GreatVibes white">Subscribe Now!</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5" id="mobile-enter-email">
                            <input type="text" name="lname" class="header-textboxemail font-Awesome white" placeholder="Email Address">
                            <button type="button" class="header-btsubscribe font-GaramondPremierePro">SUBSCRIBE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.header-subscribe-section {background-color:#ad1f34; height:99.27px; width:100%}
.header-p-latestmenus{font-size:20px; letter-spacing:0.5px;}
.header-p-subscribe{font-size:28px; letter-spacing:0.5px;}
.header-btsubscribe{border-radius:4px; background-color:#831024; color:white; width:134.55px; height:44.19685px; width:146.19685px; border:none;font-size:18px;}
.header-textboxemail{width: 286.779527559px;height: 46.19685px;font-size: 17px;border: 0;}
.header-subscribe-section p{padding: 4% 14%;}
```

[header-subscribe-section: the alignment can be changed for mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba24u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can add col-xs-36 to your parents div and usually we set inputs width 100% in smaller screen

change width property in your css file to 100%
ande remove height